# How to pass to the SeconViewController as the list must show broad list of text in the FirstViewController

Tags: ios, json

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    let category = result?.data[indexPath.row]
    
    let vc = ListViewController(items: result!.data) 
    vc.title = category?.title
    vc.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    
}
```

ListViewController is the second Vc as i want to show category of result in there
First Vc works when it opens up but when i click the cell of tableview it doesnt go to ListViewController.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You want `self.navigationController`, not `vc.navigationController`; your new view controller won't have a navigation controller until you push it onto one.

Comment: @Paulw11 You mean i shouls change it to self?